# PL230 DMA & PL022 SPI transmit only 9 bytes

Tags: spi, dma

I am trying to implement SPI+DMA on [W7500](https://docs.wiznet.io/img/products/w7500/w7500x_rm_v112_20181017_.pdf). The chip has a [PL230 DMA](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f74b4911b758617cd95b9e6?token=) and [PL022 SPI](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5e8e3b2afd977155116a92f7?token=) (with 8 level FIFOs). First I just want to transmit N bytes using DMA [basic](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/training/mcu/efm32-series-0-dma.pdf) mode. **On the pins I only see 9 bytes** (or less if I request less than 9). They all have the correct values.

This is my code:

```
static uint8_t spi_tx_buffer[] =
    {0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
     0x18, 0x19, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27};

void spi_init(void) {
    PAD_AFConfig(PAD_PC, GPIO_Pin_12, PAD_AF2);  // CS0
    PAD_AFConfig(PAD_PC, GPIO_Pin_13, PAD_AF2);  // SCK0
    PAD_AFConfig(PAD_PC, GPIO_Pin_14, PAD_AF2);  // MISO0
    PAD_AFConfig(PAD_PC, GPIO_Pin_15, PAD_AF2);  // MOSI0

    CRG_SSPCLK_SourceSelect(CRG_RCLK);  // use 8 MHz internal RCO as peripheral clock

    SSP0->CR0 =
        SSP_CR0_DSS_0 | SSP_CR0_DSS_1 | SSP_CR0_DSS_2 /* 8-bit frame*/;

    SSP0->CPSR = 16;  // prescaler

    SSP0->CR1 = SSP_CR1_SSE;  // enable the peripheral

    DMA->DMA_CFG = 0; /* Disable DMA controller for initialization */
    DMA->CTRL_BASE_PTR = (unsigned int)&GLOBAL_dma_descriptors.Primary;
    DMA->CHNL_ENABLE_CLR = 0x3F; /* Disable all channels */
    DMA->DMA_CFG = 1;            /* Enable DMA controller */

    spi_transfer(spi_tx_buffer, sizeof(spi_tx_buffer));
}

void spi_transfer( uint8_t *data, uint32_t length) {
    
    uint32_t control1 = (3 /*no increment*/ << 30) |                     /* dst_inc */
                        (0 /*byte size*/ << 28) |                        /* dst_size */
                        (0 /*byte increment*/ << 26) |                   /* src_inc */
                        (0 /*byte size*/ << 24) |                        /* src_size */
                        (0 /*non-cacheable*/ << 21) |                    /* dst_prot_ctrl - HPROT[3:1] */
                        (0 /*non-cacheable*/ << 18) |                    /* src_prot_ctrl - HPROT[3:1] */
                        (0 /*arbitrate between every transfer*/ << 14) | /* R_power */
                        ((length - 1) << 4) |                            /* n_minus_1 */
                        (1 << 3) |                                       /* next_useburst */
                        (1 /*basic mode*/ << 0);                         /* cycle_ctrl */

    GLOBAL_dma_descriptors.Primary[DMA_SSP0].Control = control1;
    GLOBAL_dma_descriptors.Primary[DMA_SSP0].SrcEndPointer = (uint32_t)data + length - 1;
    GLOBAL_dma_descriptors.Primary[DMA_SSP0].DestEndPointer = (uint32_t)&SSP0->DR;

    __DSB();

    DMA->CHNL_ENABLE_SET = (1 << DMA_SSP0);             // enable DMA channel
    SSP0->DMACR = SSP_DMACR_TXDMAE | SSP_DMACR_RXDMAE;  // enable DMA signals
}
```

Things I checked:

- DMA descriptor alignment (256 bytes)
- Enabling TXDMAE, RXDMAE, and any combination in the SPI peripheral
- Different R_power settings in the DMA
- Different lengths (lengths below 9 bytes work fine)

I tried reading the `DR` register independently from firmware in case the peripheral stops requesting TX bytes because the RX FIFO is full. I did not help.

I also added another channel to receive data from the SPI FIFO:

```
// TX direction
    uint32_t control1 = (3 /*no increment*/ << 30) |                     /* dst_inc */
                        (0 /*byte size*/ << 28) |                        /* dst_size */
                        (0 /*byte increment*/ << 26) |                   /* src_inc */
                        (0 /*byte size*/ << 24) |                        /* src_size */
                        (0 /*non-cacheable*/ << 21) |                    /* dst_prot_ctrl - HPROT[3:1] */
                        (0 /*non-cacheable*/ << 18) |                    /* src_prot_ctrl - HPROT[3:1] */
                        (0 /*arbitrate between every transfer*/ << 14) | /* R_power */
                        ((length - 1) << 4) |                            /* n_minus_1 */
                        (1 << 3) |                                       /* next_useburst */
                        (3 /*ping pong*/ << 0);                          /* cycle_ctrl */

    GLOBAL_dma_descriptors.Primary[DMA_SSP0].Control = control1;
    GLOBAL_dma_descriptors.Primary[DMA_SSP0].SrcEndPointer = (uint32_t)data + length - 1;
    GLOBAL_dma_descriptors.Primary[DMA_SSP0].DestEndPointer = (uint32_t)&SSP0->DR;
    // RX direction
    uint32_t control2 = (0 /*byte increment*/ << 30) |                   /* dst_inc */
                        (0 /*byte size*/ << 28) |                        /* dst_size */
                        (3 /*no increment*/ << 26) |                     /* src_inc */
                        (0 /*byte size*/ << 24) |                        /* src_size */
                        (0 /*non-cacheable*/ << 21) |                    /* dst_prot_ctrl - HPROT[3:1] */
                        (0 /*non-cacheable*/ << 18) |                    /* src_prot_ctrl - HPROT[3:1] */
                        (0 /*arbitrate between every transfer*/ << 14) | /* R_power */
                        ((length - 1) << 4) |                            /* n_minus_1 */
                        (1 << 3) |                                       /* next_useburst */
                        (3 /*ping pong*/ << 0);                          /* cycle_ctrl */

    GLOBAL_dma_descriptors.Alternate[DMA_SSP0].Control = control2;
    GLOBAL_dma_descriptors.Alternate[DMA_SSP0].SrcEndPointer = (uint32_t)&SSP0->DR;
    GLOBAL_dma_descriptors.Alternate[DMA_SSP0].DestEndPointer = (uint32_t)data + length - 1;
    __DSB();
    DMA->CHNL_ENABLE_SET = (1 << DMA_SSP0);             /* Enable channel */
    SSP0->DMACR = SSP_DMACR_TXDMAE | SSP_DMACR_RXDMAE;  // enable DMA signals
```

Strangely, now I get only 8 bytes out but the receive buffer in RAM is overwritten completely (meaning that at least `length` RX transfers have happened).

The MCU is a little bit strange because all SPI TX & RX signals are wired to the same DMA channel. I also can't find any example of SPI+DMA for this chip.
[image: reference manual screenshot with DMA channel mapping]

Answer (score 1):

You enable both TX and RX DMA, but there is only a TX channel set up. Either don't enable RX DMA or set up another channel for the RX data.

The SPI peripherial runs until the RX buffers are full.